# Testing URLs with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Assuming I have an array of URLs and I want to ensure each URL is working I have created the following code.  However only the last URL in the array is getting tested.  How can I ensure each url returns a 200 response code?  To be clear these are all remote addresses I am testing and they point to decently sized PDFs.

Updated based on @lukas.pukenis's response.  The results are similar, only a few files are actually checked.

```
function check(l) {
    console.log(l);

    http.get(l, function(res) {
        if (res.statusCode != 200) {
            console.log(res.statusCode + ' on '+l);
        } else {
            console.log('success on ' + l);
        }
    });
}

for (link in fileLinks) {
  check(fileLinks[link]);
}
```

This code outputs:

```
http://somesite.com/somefile1.pdf
http://somesite.com/somefile2.pdf
http://somesite.com/somefile3.pdf
...
all the rest of them
...
http://somesite.com/somefile99.pdf
success on http://somesite.com/somefile1.pdf
success on http://somesite.com/somefile2.pdf
404 on http://somesite.com/somefile5.pdf
success on http://somesite.com/somefile7.pdf
```

Comment: If `fileLinks` is an Array, try using the `.forEach(function(item){})` function instead of `for`, which is used to loop through the various keys in a javascript object. It's not meant to be used with arrays.

Answer (score 1):

This is because your loop rewrites l variable each time with         `var l = fileLinks[link];`

so l has a value of the last value of array.
In order to preserve unique **l** value you need to store it somewhere. Better - function. Like this:

```
function check(l) {
  var req = http.get(l, function(res) {
    if (res.statusCode != 200) {
      console.log(res.statusCode + ' on '+l);
    } else {
      console.log('success on ' + l);
    }
  }

  req.on('close', function() {
    console.log('Request done');
  });

for (link in fileLinks) {
  var l = fileLinks[link];
  check(l);
}
```

Having a function is no magic here. It just preserves your local values in memory for each function call, so **l** is unique each time it needs to be.

Comment: Thanks Lukas.  This helped but still didn't fix the issue.  I updated the question to reflect your suggested edits.

Comment: Are you sure your array gets iterated correctly? for .. in .. loop is used for object iteraction. Please show your dataset or just a structure of it :)

Comment: It's just an array of strings. I think it's looping because the log entry before the .get call is still being written for every record.  I'm guessing that the .get call is being executed in the background and nodemon isn't waiting for execution to finish before closing the app.

Comment: Can you tell me what happens if you modify your code according to my updated code? I have read that node waits until all callback pools are empty and you can add your event with .on() so give it a try :)

Answer (score 1):

The `for` expression shouldn't be used with arrays. Replace the `for` loop for something like this:

```
fileLinks.forEach(function(item){
  check(item);
});
```

When doing this many outgoing requests, you may want to increase the `maxSockets` to something greater than 5, [the default](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_agent), otherwise you might get unexpected behavior. Do this after you `require('http')`:

```
http.globalAgent.maxSockets = 150;
```

Also, when you stick your `console.log` outside the callback function, it's not going to be displayed at the same time the response comes back from the server. It's redundant anyway. Here is a complete working example:

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');

function check(l) {
  var u = url.parse(l);

  var opts = {
    host: u.host,
    path: u.path,
    agent: false // prevents pooling behavior
  };

    http.get(opts, function(res) {
        if (res.statusCode != 200) {
            console.log(res.statusCode + ' on '+l);
        } else {
            console.log('success on ' + l);
        }
    });
}

fileLinks = ['http://www.google.com','http://www.google.com'];

fileLinks.forEach(function(item){
  check(item);
});
```

Comment: Your example works as does Lukas's.  The maxSockets setting helps but still the app closes before all requests complete.  In your example 150 are processed then another 12 or so then the app just closes.

Comment: Try setting `agent` to `false` to disable the pooling behavior.

Comment: Err, I was wrong about that false option. I just edited my answer. Try that.